# jQuery - traversing up one parent and setting the ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to grab the text within a label - and traverse it up to the parent("li") and set it as an ID there.

It's getting the text correctly for each iterations - however I'm having issues trying to set it as an ID.

```
<script> 
    $('.collapse li label').each(function() {
       var test = $(this, '.collapse li label').text();
       $(this, '.collapse li label').parent("li").attr("id", test );
    });
</script>
```

I've also tried:

```
$('.collapse li').attr("id", test);
```

And lastly:

```
$( this ).parent('li').attr("id", test);
```

To no avail.

Please help me understand the correct way of looking at this?

Please see the picture below to better show what it is; i'm trying to achieve:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to set the `context` of a `selector` while accessing `$(this)` object,

```
 $( '.collapse li label' ).each(function() {
  var test = $(this).text();
  $(this).parent("li").attr("id", test );
 });
```

The way you coded is similar to,

```
$(this).find('.collapse li label').text();
```

So you are finding the same element. And that will not yield anything in your case.

Comment: Thank you so much!

I'll accept your answer when it will let me!

Comment: @MikeVanStan Glad to help!